# Counting valid passwords in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
passwords = ['baCr',
             '/)T.I]DdLNh)^WRIDa_z1',
             'izM!Imi',
             'NOb5VEhw$[17Q{P',
             'i',
             'J$52UY$Y',
             'T',
             '3',
             '{77Vt3=2WOCpKWN?',
             '$*K',
             'H2@u.yUON(i;?',
             'zr',
             '/}YrhZ7T,X^/}cM0BvR@S)Le$/$Yg@',
             'XUGc%',
             '+$?D]',
             '4?!-G}',
             'iMI!G5q]bwI-fE1VT{8rsHWX2tk$29',
             'E@',
             'lVSh;W9:RyM%Zl9L*;',
             'vWYJ%-v?^d:(o',
             '.(tp?Hxu{[D+cAhmXGM{ahV3a_fZ!',
             '3SXUCASo8/3psxL0p5mw=uf',
             '%%7h',
             'e(d',
             'Ef98S2EUy)mT9MU{@F:zE^8Pb]mg)k',
             'k',
             'ji[Wtw.#9F$GN%ymi-FU',
             'HX?z74lGp]TLqlGp[cRV!w(5]s?7m9',
             '5eL',
             'Zcrod:Xm',
             '}t8bj:RJ4BA6i+x$PlbKL$NNIj',
             'H)u(7{lK?Mk!cvUBkzlHXfFyeTL%Sh',
             '/]AA-R0A',
             'Qq1L$:(s',
             'HoDUEPlaKAnDo2;W5}FlY)H(9I',
             't0UVz3xgM2Js',
             'XJ=@Y=P)z@%7',
             'hnDTB7vtCa!MsAIR',
             '{R/BvTB?iNS!vKntp$,tvwIC7',
             '}2Lz.K',
             'P9?+AgbGhp${uMoLqwS(aajG9P.b',
             'eldDgR6SZ:v6w^G6ru*vo-',
             '-{2{4',
             'A=',
             'Z{G2p{-#Kz/c}8utFm=WPH_:uTQiT',
             'Ql91',
             '9R.6J@Y.jWs/}XA0TV4%uRi_k43',
             'zcy.Vqfk2xpwgNt-KW?$m',
             'X+O+NGT}',
             '}]2_',
             'Mcuz1;xCE{iHRhsO695ef',
             ';Q4!nRV7[,LvLDRjke1',
             '3BJi9XZW',
             '+Rot!',
             'nP.kqo1-g2G8ZT$2wxRwI8MAMJ',
             '^,$^F7:X=DkDUa?3,L{wf',
             '56',
             '#O/7CHV4WoMRmq^j$J$/Hk6DUD',
             'WkWI5O1J017)5.%!dAaVLhoW',
             ')$;',
             '{5QjA.g:xO#P1',
             'M]J%Dxc2]xxc1Kyn7=Ga+sx!@-B9',
             ':WA',
             '2?@',
             'HwH_sUUd-i$ln178038#kiQ7T@kZ;',
             '13}VI',
             'QV+',
             '2r-%+=:V',
             'DM(DYS),Z==A}',
             'fhtmcFtG)CQY0YrB7Aq%0Oogv]g',
             '-WFuVnPpZ?z@E{H3I#_:h-v^w9K',
             'ceg4g-Y',
             'yK8D5*om',
             '_ic55w$6N/3/00c',
             '^*BhAG4m',
             'w#PW',
             'D%=^j}l/Qr1l#V*%8d',
             '6tJNCnrx,)Fv6*+;q.;PCx1);',
             '}Q?}pvhv=beW',
             'W$$.C5cI9;Grs653}-5(@p/Nb@8i',
             '{(:F6LI',
             'r]l@?Fy',
             '@N4[qs{!P{Kb[t_sB',
             'xoL:UAe(7m$4gjtuakk-ViLNu^b',
             'Hc]1:eqc%TzXy8n-?s7VQG.#[nm',
             'sM:pqfC',
             '8XVO5X7lwt8!B6',
             '{$[^',
             '7SiL3',
             'hV_yN(Kh19%M)5PDV)9oQ5?y*k%2',
             '}UhE!SxN7qQVdiNXuw8N+Xxio%I',
             'KK:',
             '+ZsrD?az!I',
             '@_',
             'roX:*+2Dl#@k-io',
             '7Dq',
             'TBQ[5',
             '9/CX',
             'e74j*J^oD',
             '1KRmy=FjO[P?kd#+zNQV9:uL(vP',
             'di?hp0L*6VZf9:',
             '24?%6GW%',
             'S@',
             'hI7TS!Jo2J2$Zp/_^aIK^(v{K4+',
             'W*zIb',
             'Qlu@bPU6UtNd',
             'n9yX]z0xBQ3C$BG4Jk/,#MG4j[',
             'u',
             'xL!b.A!zUn',
             'I21%',
             'ff1Vf=fWqL:sg$gfKnA7;R',
             '!6A#W!jwnB-fPP1hGK]sA!B@uitkj',
             'qNf.B35u0),}eL)',
             'gXB.8I$bQ',
             '9v2q0An',
             'F?9HZ4',
             'z]bgZ8wHsLJQvT!gh(Yn5o[',
             'w)K{[3{Z0%u^q',
             'SD',
             '#c)RM554mY!YD93',
             '09YNkm.@VyMPC8cQg5',
             'R1}Jw!-rV=Bo{A9@/aWuuP',
             'n/CC5xU3hC.itVaF,R=?[^',
             '[RiM[xNb',
             '=I',
             ':M[Z%WY,w0.:{c;69ESv_@4S)#n',
             'D6-9s.,f=pXiuMF;!l}!N]',
             'L?2',
             '=#l4,5',
             'ZAdAEkQzdmc[O[A,H%9]3}i?',
             '0%,OVJ9/}([L[Nq=3mgS:sYHa;',
             'Y4:*NU',
             '$To.Ce7:hd#YgKFZr+1i.Lx)BIuH',
             'nM)@%*H9GiXevMmVm.(Z)]:!BxU!r',
             'h?(Y_',
             'F(qqHrvx5kL[Xx=4lcs:H!A',
             'TgIT+I;GClgST/NB*',
             '6=}.',
             '+4',
             '+BQ5C}:6',
             'Dh5VF2Ek#a',
             'REB4k%v.c1J*vq?F3#2',
             '8}JCK',
             '#{?2[X?M[A!_O]RVKqVv%93_@]vx,$',
             'H44z_DwaG/A,g)xBCG+9GjAh7e]$!',
             'jgct7fezi;jtqc*',
             '(_',
             '.3:',
             'eM4mx)S9HDq_,*rZ;LE0S=U4L2i',
             '-]F]']
```

and I need to find passwords meeting all of the following criteria:

- Must not contain any more than 15 characters
- Cannot contain any lowercase characters (a-z)
- The first and last character cannot be the same

This is my code:

```
valid=0
for password in passwords:
    if len(password)<=15 and password.upper() and password[0]!=password[-1]: valid+=1
```

I believe the answer is 38, but I keep getting 85? Does anyone see an error in my code that would return the wrong answer? Thanks.

Comment: `password.upper()` is always true. You want `password.upper() == password` (i.e. if you capitalize the letters in the password it remains the same, meaning all the letters were already uppercase)

Comment: `password.upper()` will always return True for a non-empty string.

Comment: What you want is `password.isupper()` @kindall

Comment: @Barmar `'@_'.isupper()` is False, but it's less than 15 chars, and characters dont match... That should be valid, according to the logic

Comment: Yeah, `password.isupper()` requires at least one letter, which is not a rule.

Answer (score 2):

`password.upper()` returns the password in caps. You need to check they are the same with `password.upper() == password`:

```
valid = 0
for password in passwords:
    if len(password) <= 15 and password.upper() == password and password[0] != password[-1]:
        valid += 1
```

```
>>> valid
38
```

---

You can see what is happening here:

```
>>> x = "abc"
# Check the truthiness of x (this is what you were originally doing)
# A non-empty string is always True
>>> bool(x)
True
# x.upper() will just return an uppercase copy
>>> x.upper()
'ABC'
# You need to compare the original with the upper
>>> bool(x == x.upper())
False
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to check if no lowercase characters (a-z) are present:

```
import re

passwords = [
    'baCr', 
    '/)T.I]DdLNh)^WRIDa_z1',
    'izM!Imi', 
    'NOb5VEhw$[17Q{P', 
    'i',
    ...
]

valid = 0
for password in passwords:
    if len(password) <= 15 and not re.search('[a-z]', password) and password[0] != password[-1]:
        valid += 1
print(f'{valid = }')
```

**Output:**

```
valid = 38
```

Comment: @OneCriketeer Just FYI in case you haven't seen it [f-strings support = for self-documenting expressions and debugging](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging). If you have do you recommend not using it in answers?

Comment: Oh neat. Feel free to revert

Comment: It's my favorite feature :)

Answer (score 1):

Another version:

```py
import re

valid, pat = 0, re.compile(r"([^a-z])[^a-z]{,13}[^\1a-z]$")
for p in passwords:
    valid += bool(pat.match(p))

print(valid)
```

Prints:

```
38
```

Comment: For those that need explaining the regex: Doesn't start with `a-z` range, isn't followed by 13 more `a-z`, and does not end with the first matched character or character in `a-z` range

Comment: `sum(1 for p in passwords if re.match(r"([^a-z])[^a-z]{,13}[^\1a-z]$", p))` for those who like one-liners.